# How to sum each row in a .xts object, where values are NOT missing

Tags: r, xts, na, data-manipulation

I currently have a line of code set up to sum each row/date of a xts object, where value for each data point = 1:

```
   universe.rt=sapply(X=2:nrow(rt),FUN=function(x){sum(rt[x,which(live[x,]==1)])/count[x]})
```

I want to change the code such that instead of summing up all points in a row where value = 1, I want to sum all points in a row where value is NOT NA:

```
   universe.rt=sapply(X=2:nrow(rt),FUN=function(x){sum(rt[x,which(live[x,]==!is.na)])/count[x]})
```

I can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is.na is a function, you should use

```
which(!is.na(live[x,]))
```

Answer (score 4):

for xts objects, you should use `rowSums` rather than `sapply`, because the apply functions use loops internally, and `rowSums` calls out to faster C code.

```
rowSums(x,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional input Brian - it is much faster now!